# Java Error: illegal start of the expressions

Tags: java

```
public class Flatten {
    public static int[] flatten(int[][] x) {
        int totalLength = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (x[i].length > 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {
                    totalLength += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        int[] a = new int[totalLength];
        int aIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (x[i].length > 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {
                    a[aIndex] = x[i][j];
                    aIndex += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] test = flatten({{1, 2, 3}, {}, {7, 8}});     // Error line
        for(int i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
            System.out.print(test[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Hi guys! This is a short code in my homework file. When I run the code, the terminal shows that "=" is illegal. I do not know where the problem is. Hope you guys can help me find out :)

Answer (score 3):

The only time you can omit the type on an array initializer is when you are **declaring** an array variable. For example,

```
int[] test = flatten({{1, 2, 3}, {}, {7, 8}});
```

could be

```
int[][] tempArr = {{1, 2, 3}, {}, {7, 8}};
int[] test = flatten(tempArr);
```

**or**

```
int[] test = flatten(new int[][] {{1, 2, 3}, {}, {7, 8}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it in this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = {{1, 2, 3}, {}, {7, 8}};
    int[] test = flatten(arr);     // Error line
    for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(test[i] + " ");
    }
}
```